# How do you measure a Fourier coefficient?

Tags: fourier-transform

An MRI machine is capable of measuring Fourier coefficients directly (a strange idea, at first).  But understanding MRI is somewhat complicated, and involves some knowledge of quantum physics.

Is there a much simpler physical system or device that is also capable of measuring Fourier coefficients?  Perhaps something involving just a spring-mass system?  This might shed light on the question "how is it possible to measure a Fourier coefficient".

Is there a simple way to explain the basic physical mechanism or idea that allows us to measure Fourier coefficients?  For example, is the main idea that if some measurement device is excited **only at its resonant frequency**, and we check how excited the measurement device is, then this allows us to know how much of that particular frequency is present in whatever oscillating system we are measuring?

Comment: Directly? Are you sure they don't take the signal then integrate against sine/cosine the way we do it in intro PDE classes?

Comment: Yes, directly.  In MRI the basic strategy is to measure Fourier coefficients of an image (of the human body) directly, then use the inverse Fourier transform (or inverse DFT) to recover the image, which was not available to us in advance.

Comment: You might want to edit the question to make clear you're talking about fourier coefficients of an image (thus with location as independent variable) instead of the coefficients of a time-varying signal (with time as independent variable), because the answer to how to measure it is likely to be very different.

Comment: For the case of how to measure coefficients for a time domain signal, look up *spectrum analyzer*, a standard piece of lab equipment that (historically) did exactly this.